# Pandas Groupby and Orderby with Rank and Summary Statistics

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm looking to use `pandas` to group, rank, and get summary statistics on a key of values for data. Say I have data like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'g_one': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 
    'g_two': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'], 
    'g_three': [10, 5, 8, 12, 3, 9]})
```

I'd like to be able to group by `g_one` and `g_two`, rank by `g_three` and then get averages for all `g_three` values, means, etc.

I've tried grouping and sorting, but haven't had success with ranking the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.groupby(['g_one', 'g_two'],as_index=False).mean().sort_values(by='g_three')
```

Output:

```
    g_one   g_two   g_three
1   2       B       4.0
2   3       C       8.5
0   1       A       11.0
```

Comment: This doesn't have a rank column included, but is close enough for me to accept the answer. I'm essentially looking to add this on as well `.rank(ascending = False)`